# Determine sum mod p

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

I want to calculate

$$
\sum_{k = 1}^{p-1} k^n \,\,\,\,\,\text{(mod $p$)}
$$

with the knowledge $n \not\equiv 0 $ (mod $p-1$), where $n \geq 1$ and $p$ is an odd prime.

Comment: If n is odd then this is 0 (mod p). Note that you're adding an even amount of numbers (from 1 to p-1). The first number is equivalent to $1^n$ and the last to $-1^n$. The same happens to the second one nd the first before last and so on. Since there's an even amount, they all cancel out. I'm trying to see what happens for even n

Comment: Do you know about the existence of primitive roots? This is an overkill solution, so don't be bothered if you aren't aware of it. I am unsure if a solution for $n$ even exists without this, though.

Comment: @rah4927 I do know the definition of a primitive roots, but do not have much knowledge about their properties.

Comment: I am getting that this is equivalent to $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} k^r$ where r is the remainder of n modulo p-1. I don't know if this answer is useful to you though

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio The odd case definitely makes sense. Thank you already!

Comment: If $\gcd (n,p-1) = 1$, then $\{ k^n \bmod p : 1 \leqslant k < p\}$ is the same set as $\{ k : 1 \leqslant k < p\}$. If $1 < \gcd (n,p-1) = d < p-1$, what do you know about the set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $n$ does not divide $p-1$. Then the map
$$x \mapsto x^n$$
from $\mathbb{F}_p^\times \to \mathbb{F}_p^\times$ is surjective, since $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$ is a cyclic group of order $p-1$. To see this, let $g$ be a generator of $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$. Then $g^n$ is still a generator of the group and is in the image. So in fact the map is bijective since it is between finite sets of same cardinality.

So, we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} k^n \equiv \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} k \pmod {p}
$$
and the last sum is zero when $p$ is an odd prime. To see this, pair off terms: this is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2} k + (p-k) \equiv \sum_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2} 0 \pmod p.
$$

Comment: This is really nice! Thank you so much ^^

Comment: But why can we suppose that $n$ does not divide $p - 1$? $2 \not\equiv 0$ (mod $4$), but $2$ does divide 4.

Comment: You're right. Try the general case, it still works!

Comment: You just get a sum which vanishes, repeated the set number of times as the order of the kernel.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{Z}/(p\mathbb{Z})^*$ is a cyclic group (it is the multiplicative part of a finite field), hence all the non-zero remainders $\!\!\pmod{p}$ can be represented as $g^r$ for $r\in[1,p-1]$, with $g$ being one of the $\varphi(p-1)$ generators of $\mathbb{Z}/(p\mathbb{Z})^*$. In particular, for any $n$ which is not a multiple of $p-1$

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k^n \equiv \sum_{r=1}^{p-1} g^{rn}\equiv \frac{g^{pn}-1}{g^n-1}-1\equiv\frac{g^n-1}{g^n-1}-1\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$
where $\frac{1}{g^n-1}$ stands for the inverse of $g^n-1\pmod{p}$.